# UITableView reload data works, but cells don't update on screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, reloaddata

I'm changing the text in a label within a UITableViewCell.  I'm doing it in the main thread.  I'm logging that I'm doing it to prove that my update is being called.

The update is not being reflected on-screen.

FWIW, I've done this dozens of times before and it has worked.  I don't get what I might be doing differently this time.

I Googled for ideas.  99% of the answers are "make sure you dispatch to main thread" (I'm doing that), 3% are "make sure your tableview is wired up and your cellForIndexPath is being called" (that's done).  The other 1.5% are miscellaneous horrid answers written by people guessing.  ;)

Some code (the important bits are the last few lines.  The rest is just setup):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // blah blah snip.

   NSString * const cellID = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellID];
   if (cell == nil)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellID];
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   }

   // blah blah more snip

   // setup progress label
   // >>>Solution<<< (thanks @Dennis !) -- wrong label here.  Should be cellProgressTag
   UILabel *lProgress = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag: cellDescriptionTag];
   if (lProgress == nil)
   {
       float startX = 0;
       CGRect lRect = lTitle.frame;
       CGRect frame = CGRectMake(startX, (lRect.origin.y + lRect.size.height), (width - startX), 18);
       lProgress = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: frame];
       lProgress.tag = cellProgressTag;
       UIFont *font = lProgress.font;
       lProgress.font = [font fontWithSize: 14];
       lProgress.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
       lProgress.textColor = textColor;
       [cell.contentView addSubview: lProgress];
   }

   // blah blah more snip

   // fill-out cell
   NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
   // blah blah more snip
   lProgress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"current level: %d     %@", currentLevel, neededStr];
   if ([key isEqualToString: @"EE"])   NSLog(@"%s %@ lProgress: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, (([NSThread isMainThread]) ? @"(main thread)" : @"NOT MAIN THREAD"), lProgress); // DEBUG
   lDescr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", _descriptionPrefix, [oneTech objectForKey: @"description"]];

   return cell;
}
```

Sample log output:

```
2015-04-11 09:11:01.074 worfc[20202:5918312] -[myapp tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (main thread) lProgress: <UILabel: 0x815bd5f0; frame = (30 53; 320 30); text = 'current level: 0     74.1...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 102; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x815bd6b0>>
2015-04-11 09:11:03.925 worfc[20202:5918312] -[myapp tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (main thread) lProgress: <UILabel: 0x815bd5f0; frame = (30 53; 320 30); text = 'current level: 0     76.6...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 102; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x815bd6b0>>
```

Yet the `lProgress` label only ever updates if I hide & reshow the table (it's in a view controller I can pop up.)  I'm trying to get the table to update live, as the result of a notification.  (Yes, that's why I dispatch to main thread.)

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: The table in question is displayed in a `UIViewController` which, itself, is displayed within a `UIPopoverController`.  I don't think it should matter, but that's slightly unusual from every other time I've done this.  Do I need to do something  special to get cell content within a popover to update?

Comment: Turns out to be a stupid copy/paste error and me not-correctly-reading my code (thanks, @Dennis !)  Is there a way to "close" dumb questions?

Comment: I think it's still not a stupid question. The fact that the tag assigned can lead to such an effect is valuable information to anyone searching for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if that is the issue, but the tags of the label do not match. You try to get it with `cellProgressTag`:

```
UILabel *lProgress = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag: cellDescriptionTag];
```

but when it is `nil`, you create the label and set tag `cellProgressTag`:

```
lProgress.tag = cellProgressTag;
```

That way, the next time you ask for the view with tag `cellProgressTag` you will get `nil` again.

Comment: Duh.  That's exactly the problem.  Simple copy/paste error.  I knew it had to be something simple/stupid.  Thanks!

Comment: And, actually, the next time I look for it, I get the other label -- the one with `cellDescriptionTag`.  I can't **tell** you how many times I looked this over and just read-right-past it.

D'oh!

Comment: Glad it helped. I know, I know, these things happen to all of us. ;)